# Error while compiling lex and yacc in mac os

Tags: xcode, macos, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I'm working on a lex and yacc program, on my devise MAC OS..

when I try to do the following:

```
gcc sample.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll
```

it shows me a lot of errors and at the end ..

**fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]**

some of the error appears :

```
./sample.tab.h:44:6: error: expected identifier 
     if = 260,
     ^
./sample.tab.h:46:6: error: expected identifier
     else = 262,
     ^
./sample.tab.h:48:6: error: expected identifier
     while = 264,
     ^
./sample.tab.h:53:6: error: expected identifier
     return = 269,
```

Could anyone help me with that??

Thank you..

Comment: [mcve] please. There just isn't enough information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use C keywords as names for non-terminals. That is why it is usual to use ALL-CAPS as non-terminal names. So you flex file might include

```
while    { return WHILE; }
return  {  return  RETURN; }
```

and if you are bison you can declare aliases:

```
%token WHILE "while"
%token RETURN "return"
```

Allowing you to write rules like:

```
whileStatement: "while" '(' expression ')' statement
```